# Count number of pixels in range of values in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, masking, pixel, count

I have raster with NDVI values and I would like to use reducer in order to know how many pixels in the raster are smaller than 0.2, between 0.2-0.4 , betwen 0.4-0.6 and gt than 0.6.

i'm not sure that the way I have been that gives me true results, because I have difference between the total number of pixels to the sum of the differnt categories pixel counts.

```
    var c0406 = image.gt(0.4).lt(0.6).selfMask().reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.count(),
    geometry: geometry,
    crs: 'EPSG:4326',
    //maxPixels:1310361348,
    scale: 20,
  }).values().get(0);
```

when each time I have change the condition in image.gt

I'm not sure it's correct because when I calculte the total number of pixels, I get 17,748 , but when I calculte the categories pixels I get around 45k:

```
   var total = image.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.count(),
    geometry: geometry,
    crs: 'EPSG:4326',
    //maxPixels:1310361348,
    scale: 30,
  }).values().get(0);
```

[image]

*i'm not sure what is systen asset size and if it's also suppose to be number of pixels

**My end goal is to count correctly the number of pixels between different ranges (0.2-0.4 ect.)**

Answer (score 1):

You have different scales in the two `reduceRegion()` calls. One is using 30 meters, the other 20 meters. With a scale of 20 meters you would get more pixels than with a scale of 30 meters.

Comment: you are right about this, I fixed it, but still getting total of 39876 and when I manually sum the different ranges I get 45,576 . (fixed everything so scale is 20 in all the ranges)